# UITableViewCell styling resetting when scrolled off and back onto view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I currently have a TableView in my project, which is set up to turn a cell green when it is pressed, and back to clear if it is pressed a second time. However, if I scroll down to the bottom of the table view, and scroll back up, all my cells have been reset to their default clear colour.

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this issue, as anything I can find referring to it is in Objective-C rather than Swift. Any help and advice as to how to go about this would be great, thanks.

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: Nothing, I am still learning and all I have done is browsed the posts of others trying to find out what to do, but I can't figure out the reason for this happening, nor how to go about a solution.

Comment: @Ethan, how you cache selected cell index? For this, you should keep the cell index in the Array. didSelectRowAtIndexPath - you have to add the index in the Array if it's not present. If it is already present remove the cell index from Array. "cellForRowAtIndexPath" check the cell index wheather it is selected or not!!!

Comment: So I could remove it from the array, and when it comes back onto view check if it is in the array or not, and if not, reimplement the styling?

Comment: Yeah, you can write logic. How you want to reimplement the style... @EthanHumphries

Comment: I think I've just about got it now, it removes the matching values of cells from an array when pressed, and I should be able to sort it from here, probably with an if statement in the part of my code that sets up the cell, giving it two options of either the default or the selected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime a UITableViewCell goes out of the screen, any function that you've written in the tableViewController/ViewController runs again.

for example in cellForRowAtIndexPath if you have a cell.setUpCell() or something similar, it will rerun and reset your values to the original values.

if you have a

var name = testName in your MainVC

and you update something in your cell, you should change the name in your mainVc too.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you scroll or call `tableView.reloadData()` UITableView cells will reload. So, every time you select UITableViewCell, add selected index (indexPath.row) to an array(ex: selectedIndexArray) in your `didSelectRowAt indexPath:` delegate. If the cell you selected is already selected one, then remove the cell from **selectedIndexArray**.

And in your `cellForRowAt indexPath:` manage the cells using **selectedIndexArray**.

```
var selectedIndexArray:[Int] = [] //to save selected tableViewCells

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let isSelected = false
    for each in selectedIndexArray
    {
        if each == indexPath.row
        {
            isSelected = true
        }
    }

    if isSelected == true
    {
        //set selected cell color
    }
    else
    {
        //set default cell color
    }
}
```

You need to write the logic of adding and removing cell indexes in your `didSelectRowAt indexPath:`.